# Some Lines of Code Dont Run

Tags: java, swing, visible

I am making a chat client, but I am having some problems with the code not running.

```
public static void login(String userName, String password) throws XMPPException {

    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com",5222,"Work");
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

    try{
        connection.connect();
        connection.login(userName, password);
        System.out.println("Login Successful");
        //gui.removeAll();

        URL temp = start.class.getResource("slate.png");

        gui.window.remove(gui.password);
        gui.window.remove(gui.username);
        gui.window.remove(gui.login);
        gui.window.remove(gui.failed);
        gui.window.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(temp)));
        gui.window.setBackground(new Color(27,27,27));

        System.out.println("Reached 1");
        //displayBuddyList();
        gui.list2.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Reached 2");
        gui.list2.setText("text test");
        System.out.println("Reached 3");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        gui.failed.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

the lines "gui.list2.setVisible(true)" and "gui.list2.setText("TestText")" seam to be not working. But I get all the System.out.println Messages.

"list2" is a JTextArea, its been adready added the JFrame I been using:
Heres the code in my gui class:

```
window.add(list2);
list2.setBounds(0,0,window.getWidth(),window.getHeight());
list2.setVisible(false);
```

For all the code for further investigation: http://pastebin.com/PcSPzgBN

Comment: Is all of this happening in the EDT? If so, is something else jamming the EDT?

Comment: Put gui.list2.setVisible(true); *after* the setText call.

Comment: @Quirliom that didnt work.

Comment: and @John3136 what is EDT?

Comment: EDT is the Event Dispatch Thread. If you jam it up Java won't get a chance to draw stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks I think so, i updated my post so you can check out the full code if you want.

Comment: @DarkLlama Yeah I saw your full source code link. I thought maybe the window was newly created and invisible (which typically means height/width are 0) but not so.

Comment: I removed 'list2.setVisiable(false)' from the gui class and it shows up but the "Test Text" doesnt show up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source code is long enough that it's hard to pinpoint exactly where the problem you've cited is. I think it might be exactly this line:

```
gui.window.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(temp))); // <- this line
gui.window.setBackground(new Color(27,27,27));

...
gui.list2.setText("text test");
...
gui.list2.setVisible(true);
```

Where after setting the content pane, `list2` is probably not in the frame anymore. It's probably on whatever was the content pane before (`gui.firstscreen`?).

There are, however, some more general problems.

I see a pattern that looks like this:

```
SomeJComponent aComp1 = new SomeJComponent();

somewhere.add(aComp1);
aComp1.setBounds(/* ... */);
aComp1.setVisible(false);

SomeJComponent aComp2 = new SomeJComponent();

somewhere.add(aComp2);
aComp2.setBounds(/* ... */);
aComp2.setVisible(false);
```

Basically it looks like you are doing this to switch out the visible components on a frame dynamically sometimes. Your components are all overlapping and you pick which ones to be visible to reconfigure the frame. I would strongly recommend against doing this.

The "correct" way to swap the view of a container is to have separate panels and set the content pane (or even better use JComponents intended for this such as JTabbedPane). The following is a short working example that does just that:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class PanelSwap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PanelSwap().frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;

    PanelSwap() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton toPanel2 = new JButton("Goto Panel 2");
        toPanel2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setContentPane(panel2);
                frame.validate();
            }
        });

        panel1.add(toPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton toPanel1 = new JButton("Goto Panel 1");
        toPanel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setContentPane(panel1);
                frame.validate();
            }
        });

        panel2.add(toPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setContentPane(panel1);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

If you want some GUI elements to be shared, you can instead set the content pane to a panel with the shared elements and add/remove elements to/from that panel. Use something like BorderLayout for the best results.

The other point is that you need to be interacting with the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the tutorial. Specifically *"Initial Threads"* and *"The Event Dispatch Thread"*.

That is what `invokeLater` is for. It is OK to update the GUI inside events (methods like `actionPerformed`) because they are executed on the EDT. Anywhere else you should use `invokeLater`. There are a few exceptions to the rule but for the most part you need to be doing Swing stuff on the EDT.

A last and more like an aside is you should really follow [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) for names, specifically classes start with an uppercase letter. Your `start` and `gui` classes should be `Start` and `GUI`. It's further confusing because your gui class has a method called `start`.

Comment: Thanks!! I cant believe adding `gui.window.add(gui.list2)` in that block solved, i will try to focus on rewriting my code soon. If I run into a problem or something can i message you?

Comment: Since I think you have enough rep to use the chat you can try to hail me there. Typing a user name with the @ (like @DarkLlama) will send a mention notification from chat as well. If I'm not on SO you can ask the question anyway. Sometimes there are others in the room or I might see it when I do get on.

Answer (score 0):

Try repainting and (re)validating the gui container (window), or the JTextArea component, after setting the component to visible.

Comment: like `window.repaint()` i tried that method on the JFrame and JTextArea